# Move notebook log console in jupyter-lab

Tags: jupyter-lab

I am using a notebook as a single data analysis gui interface by means of ipywidget.
Using the widgets performs tasks and self updates the gui.  The text output is a cronological log of the data analysis.

For this reason a good, although unusual target for the log would be the log console.
However the standard "down" location of Log console is inconvenient because of the browser aspect ratio, with limited vertical space and lots of horizontal space.

For this reason i would like to relocate the log console to the right sidebar.

I found a template in Interface Customization. Something like

```
,
    "layout": {
  "single": {
    "Log Console": { "area": "right" },
  }}
```

I think I should place this in the Jupyterlab Shell but I cannot find where this is.

Comment: What do you mean by you "found a template"? I *think* that what you are asking for is not already possibly and you would need to open a feature request on JupyterLab GitHub. I might be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Don't reinvent the wheel, just use this jupyterlab extension:
[SideCar - A Right Vertical Bar for JupyterLab](https://github.com/jupyter-widgets/jupyterlab-sidecar)